# Call a custom model method from controller laravel4

Tags: php, model, controller, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model like this:

```
class Event extends Eloquent

    {
        protected $softDelete = true;
        public function scopeSearchEvents($search_criteria)
        {
            return Event::whereIn('title',$search_criteria)
                            ->orWhereIn('description',$search_criteria)
                            ->whereApproved('1')
                            ->orderBy('event_date','desc')
                            ->get();
        }
    }
```

And im calling it from the controller like this:

```
$data = Event::search($search_criteria);
```

But it gives this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::search()
```

What is the best way of calling a custom model method from your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes to your method as given below:

```
public function scopeSearchEvents($query, $search_criteria)
{
    return $query->whereIn('title', $search_criteria)
                 ->orWhereIn('description', $search_criteria)
                 ->whereApproved('1')
                 ->orderBy('event_date','desc');
}
```

Then call it like `searchEvents` not `search`:

```
// Don't use Event as your model name
$data = YourModel::searchEvents($search_criteria)->get();
```

Also make sure that, you want to use `whereIn` instead of `where('title', 'LIKE', "% $search_criteria")` and so.

### Update:

You should change the model name from  `Event` to anything else because `Laravel` has it's core `Event` class, actually a `Facade` which is mapped to `'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event'`.

Comment: thanks for the response, but the error persists:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::searchEvents()

Do I need any extra configuration to my laravel 4 project?

Comment: No, it should work, did you use this code properly ?

Comment: You should not use `Event` as your class/model name.

Comment: yes man, i copied and pasted the code. BTW, the $search_criteria is an array that's why im using whereIn...

Comment: why i shouldnt use that name?

Comment: Laravel has it's own class using the name `Event` in the global scope. I've also updated the answer.

Comment: Alternatively you may use a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) if you want to use `Event` as your model name.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **app.php**:

```
'aliases' => array(
        ...
        'Event'=> 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        ...
);
```

**"[Event](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events)"** is defined as an alias. That's why your **[Event](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events)** calls **"Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event"**.
Now if you want to use your event model without typing the namespace to call methods create an alias like:

```
'MyEvent' => 'App\Models\Event',
```

and then:

```
MyEvent::create();
```